# All of someone else's stars in chat?

Tags: feature-request, chat, chat-stars

In the chat, a link like this one will show me all of *my* starred messages in the mathematics chatroom: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/36/mathematics/?tab=stars&filter=mymessages (However, it only will work from my account.)

Is there a way to see all the starred messages of a certain user?

Comment: you can see all the starred messages _of a room_  https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/36/mathematics/?tab=stars You cant filter another persons stars AFAIK

Comment: Also shouldnt this be in https://meta.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: @suraj Those are stars that are on peoples posts.  You can't know who stared those messages.

Comment: @NathanOliver I think Op wants to filter all the stars that a particular user _got_ in a chatroom.. Either way there doesnt exist a filter in the chat transcript

Comment: @NathanOliver  I don't _want_ to know who starred them. I want to see everything a user has posted that has become starred.

Comment: Ah, my bad.  Not sure if there is a nice way to do that.  Chat is not in SEDE so that makes it harder.